# IOS - How to load more DB records to UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, database, uiwebview

I'm trying to add database records from a web server running classic asp to my existing uiwebview page when the user reaches the bounce at the bottom of the page. I have data appended to the page on each bounce WORKING using HTML DOM javascript using:

**IOS:**

```
NSString *JavaCodeFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxx.com/JavaTestImage.asp"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *ReturnedValue = [Web_View stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", JavaCodeFromFile]];
```

**JavaTestImage.asp contents:**

```
var para=document.createElement("p"); 
var NewImg=document.createElement("img"); 
NewImg.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.xxx.com/Images/Under_Construction.jpg');
NewImg.setAttribute('width', '100');
NewImg.setAttribute('height', '120');
document.body.appendChild(NewImg); 

var Textnode=document.createTextNode("From JavaTestImage.asp - Added Text.");  
para.appendChild(Textnode); 
document.body.appendChild(para);
```

**QUESTION:**
This code works fine but because its javascript I cannot call a DB to load more records dynamically. Is there another approach I can use to add more DB data to an already populated UIWebView?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: I think PHP is your best solution.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, Can you elaborate with an example? I have no experience with PHP.

Comment: check the below answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to do that in PHP, you have to choices.

1 - Save the image file names in an SQLDB or any other DB and use a DB query to get the records.

2 - Just put all the image files in a certain folder and fetch files in that folder.

I will choose the easiest way (the second one), below is the code:

the below code should be saved as getimages.php

Assuming your images are saved in a folder named "images" and is located with getimages.php in the same folder.

The code responds with 6 records with starting record number: `(6 * ($pagenum - 1))`.

To get the first 6 records, just make your request URL string = `"www.xxx.com/getimages.php?page=1"`

```
<?php

     $pagenum = 0;
     if ( array_key_exists( 'page', $_GET ) ) {
          $pagenum = $_GET[ 'page' ] - 1;
     }

     $i = 0;
     $tmp1 = (($pagenum + 1) * 6);
     $tmp2 = $pagenum * 6;
     $entered = 0;
     foreach (array_reverse(glob("images/*.jpg")) as $filename) {
          // replace ".jpg" with ".*" if you have more than one extension
          if (($i > ($tmp2 - 1)) && ($i < $tmp1)) {

               echo "$filename" . "\n";
               $entered = 1;
      }
      $i = $i +1;
     }
?>
```

This should return a string of 6 lines, each with an image URL.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Although your code does function correctly. Including your block of code in the existing JavaTestImage.asp file returns nothing from IOS app. I've found that even adding the tags <script language=javascript></script> for my original code makes the IOS call to stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString fail. So adding <?php ?> hurts a lot, lol. Looks like I may be missing something in the way to prepare an stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString file. Any ideas?

Comment: you shouldn't call your JavaTestImage.asp , you should call the php file instead, and build your HTML string in your iOS app :)

Comment: Can't call the php file directly because the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is expecting javascript only. Or are you saying dump that call altogether? If so how will I call the DOM? Educate me as I'm obviously missing how best practice should be executed here.

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to load more images as you scroll to the bottom, you can detect the current scroll position using `int scrollPosition = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];`, use that int compared to the `UIWebView` height to get the next page to load, use that page number in calling the PHP file, and use the returned response string to construct your HTML string.

Comment: to get the response string, just use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req_str queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData,NSError *error)];` instead of your `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

Comment: Hi, got it fully working with image names from DB. Changed the php code to ASP code however. The real info that I was missing was the call to: [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req_str queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData,NSError *error)].